# matplotlib ax.add_collection() coloring problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot multiple rectangle patches in one plot. I have read that it is much faster to add the patches all at once. The problem I am facing is that the color attribute is being ignored.The patches are drawn, however only in blue.

When I add the patches one at time, there is no problem. The color attribute is crucial must be defined when the patch is created.

```
patchCollections = []
For x in list:
    rect = patches.Rectangle((x,y), 1, 1, color='{}'.format(x[1]))
    patchCollections.append(rect)
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patchCollections))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patchCollections, match_original=True))
```

By default patch collection over-rides the given color for the purposes of being able to apply a color map, cycle colors, etc. This is a collection level feature (and what powers the code behind scatter plot)

```
match_original= True
```

must be added